# Find and replace Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've read a lot of questions and I tried several Script for Google Sheets but nothing works for a very simple case:

I would love to replace all the points "." with the commas "," in a specific range (E2:E999) in the same way I could do it with a Ctrl+H command, as you can see below.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help,
Marco

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and be a bit more specific about your search/research efforts (i.e. include some links to similar questions) . Reg. [ask].

Comment: @Marco, it seems to me that you just need to change the locale of your spreadsheet(s) to Italy. **File > Spreadsheet settings > Locale: Italy**

Comment: Welcome, Marco. Values in the column "qtà richiesta" (qty required) appear to be numbers. But the "Find-and-replace" method will convert those numbers to text values, and render them useless for any future calculations. @ErikTyler sensibly suggested changing the spreadsheet locale; the effect of this would be that the values in "qtà richiesta" would continue to be numbers. Would you clarify something for me: all the examples in "qtà richiesta" are whole numbers. Do you really need to display values in this column to two decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, but in means two things:

1. you will need to insert a new column (but you can hide the one that has the decimal points)
2. It will convert the numbers into strings so you will not be able to use them for calculations (but they will look right). You will still be able to do any calculations you need using the original data (in the 'hidden' column)

Assuming that the number you want to reformat it in cell A1, then in another cell (e.g. B1), insert the following formula:

=text(A1,"00")&","&right(text(A1,"00.00"),2)

[image: An example of the formula in action]

You can also copy and "Paste values only" (Ctrl+Shift+V) so that you can then remove the original column (if you don't need it for calculations)

[image: can paste as values only]